# Finding the Point Estimate for a Proportion

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

I am trying to do part (c) in the following question from the textbook Beginning Statistics by Douglas S. Shafer and Zhiyi Zhang:

[image]

I just computed $\hat{p}=\frac{315+335}{1200}\approx 0.542$ yet the textbook answer is $\hat{p}=0.5583$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I have the same result like you. It seems that they´ve calculated $\frac{335+335}{1200}$

Comment: @callculus I see, so it is just a simple typo.

Comment: Yeah, it seems so. What is the confidence interval in d)? From that you can deduce which $\hat p$ they´ve used finally.

Comment: @callculus The answer says $(0.5214, 0.5952)$.

Comment: Then they used $(0.5214+0.5952)/2=0.5583=\hat p$ to calculate the interval.